# Error Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im constantly getting an error and it doesnt go away even when I try to cast an input text field. This my code:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var fingerNumbersInputField: UITextField!
@IBAction func guessButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomFingers = arc4random_uniform(6)
    if randomFingers == Int(fingerNumbersInputField.text!) {

    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var resultField: UILabel!
```

And this is the error I get in Xcode:

[Screenshot of the Error in Xcode CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deJ0q.png)

> Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

What is wrong with this code? Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random_uniform(6)` return `UInt32` and later you trying to compare `UInt32` and `Int?`, this is too much for compiler.
If you use modern random api like: `Int.random(0..<6)` everything should be fine

```swift
let randomFingers = Int.random(in: 0..<6)
if randomFingers == Int(fingerNumbersInputField.text!) { }
```

Comment: Oops! I didnt knew it return "UInt32" I was just expecting an "Int". Im following a course on Udemy and the guy does exactly like I did. As Swift is a modern language, I was expecting something straightforward like "Int.random" but I was just following the course as it is.

Comment: @HankMoody it was added in latest version. Your course may be little bit outdated. As long as it's on swift 4+ it should be ok.

Comment: God knows what I would have done if there was no SOF.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
if randomFingers == Int(fingerNumbersInputField.text!)! {

}
```

or savely

```
if let value = Int(fingerNumbersInputField.text!) , value == randomFingers {
      /////   
}
```

Comment: Please contribute an explanation next time, not simply an answer.